# Keyboard Extension: Processing Context Before Input Only Executes After Dismissing and Reopening Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, keyboard

I'm working on a keyboard extension for iOS, and I've encountered an issue with processing the context before the input in my replaceDocumentText function. The function is supposed to process both the text before and after the input cursor, but I'm noticing that the loop for processing the context before the input (documentContextBeforeInput) only executes after I dismiss and reopen the keyboard.

I am using KeyboardKit for this extension.

`

```
 func replaceDocumentText(textProxy: UITextDocumentProxy,       suggestionsRequired: Bool=false)  

    

  async -> (context: String, count: Int) {
    var startingOffset = 0
    var context = ""
    var forwardContextCount = 0

    //show loading only if suggestions required
    if suggestionsRequired {
        self.loadingState = .loading
    }

while let previousContext = textProxy.documentContextBeforeInput, !previousContext.isEmpty {
   /// Check for the context before the cursor
        context = previousContext + context
        startingOffset += previousContext.count
        textProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: -previousContext.count)
       
 
       try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 50_000_000)
    }
    
    // Adjust cursor from where it started
       textProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: context.count)
    
 
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000_000_000)
  
    
    
    while let nextContext = textProxy.documentContextAfterInput, !nextContext.isEmpty {
        /// Check for the context After the cursor
        forwardContextCount += 1
        context += nextContext
        textProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: nextContext.count)
    
        
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 100_000_000)
    }
    
    self.promptText = context
    self.promptCount = context.count
    
    return await withCheckedContinuation({ continuation in
        if suggestionsRequired {
            Task{
                await self.getSuggestions()

            }
        }
       
        continuation.resume(returning: (self.promptText, self.promptCount))
    })
}``
```

When I have text in the textField I press the button to read the context but this line will never executes I believe its because of ".isEmpty" condition
`while let previousContext = textProxy.documentContextBeforeInput, !previousContext.isEmpty`

But I have the text in the textField as soon I close my keyboard extension and reopens it and now on the press of button everything will work smoothly. Kindly help me with this.

I tried some text cases but not able to figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
func replaceDocumentText(textProxy: UITextDocumentProxy, suggestionsRequired: Bool = false) async -> (context: String, count: Int) {
    var context = ""
    var forwardContextCount = 0

    //show loading only if suggestions required
    if suggestionsRequired {
        self.loadingState = .loading
    }

    // Combine previous and next context directly without adjusting text position
    let previousContext = textProxy.documentContextBeforeInput ?? ""
    let nextContext = textProxy.documentContextAfterInput ?? ""
    context = previousContext + nextContext

    self.promptText = context
    self.promptCount = context.count

    return await withCheckedContinuation({ continuation in
        if suggestionsRequired {
            Task {
                await self.getSuggestions()
            }
        }
       
        continuation.resume(returning: (self.promptText, self.promptCount))
    })
}
```

Comment: No it won't work for lengthy text I have tried already and my function has been tested on 1000 words input worked fine

Comment: @irvaham: Please don't post code-only answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain what was wrong and how your code fixes the problem.